# I am having one scenario, If url was not working than i dont want to run my Test cases

Tags: javascript, java

Actually, I am hitting the URL ie gmailcom as an example, This Gmail I can access only if I do have VPN access else it gives me an error page

I am having 30 scenarios for Gmail, but I don't want to execute those scenarios if URL shows me an error

```
Error code 16
This request was blocked by the security rules

2019-05-18 18:59:37 UTC
Your IP117.98.192.121|Proxy IP45.60.125.185(ID 10747)
Incident ID: 747000100070795222-59022273854242981
```

```
String url =getUrl(prop.getProperty("url"));
System.out.println(url);


WelcomePage.ClickonLoginbutton();
loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
loginPage.login(prop.getProperty("AdminUser"), prop.getProperty("Adminpass"));
//util.waitForElementToAppear(policypage.SelectpolicyText);
Thread.sleep(40000);
adminpage= new AdminUserpage(driver);
adminpage.Controlpanelclick();
util.waitForElement(driver, 8000, adminpage.TextUserandOrg);
```

Expected: I don't want to execute my all test cases if URL was not working and page source shows me an error

Actual: After error also all Test cases running and failed

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JUnit, then you're looking for [`Assume`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html).

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions
>   in which a test is meaningful

I your case, you may want to use [assumeNoException()](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeNoException(java.lang.Throwable))

Comment: I m using Testng, Can u please elaborate your statement